# javascript popup firing only in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window.open

This is some js in one of my views:

```
var $link = '<a href="javascript:window.open(\'../EForm/Info?formId=' + data.record.Form.Id + '\',&#34;EForm Details&#34;,&#34;height=550,width=345&#34;);">info</a>';
```

I want to pop open a new small window when someone clicks on the details of an item on my page.  The code above renders this html on the page:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('../EForm/Info?formId=1',"EForm Details","height=550,width=345");">info</a>
```

which is only working in chrome (no popup blockers are enabled in IE9 or FF ) what am i doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

ok ive updated the markup same issue only works in chrome,

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('../EForm/Info?formId=1','EForm Details','height=550,width=345');">info</a>
```

**EDIT #2**

Ok think ive got the markup kinda fixed FF and IE are now opening my popup but when they do the parnt window content is replaced with [object] in IE and [Window Object] in FF.... Now what the heck is going on?

```
 <a href="javascript:window.open('../EForm/Info?formId=1','EForm_Details','height=550,width=345');">info</a>
```

Comment: Do you not see the syntax error? The syntax highlighting here on stackoverflow shows it pretty clearly. You need to escape the quotes. `\&#34;`

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are not escaping double quotes.

Modified:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('../EForm/Info?formId=1','EForm Details','height=550,width=345');">info</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so this article pointed me to my solution.  [Popup errors Object Window](http://forums.asp.net/p/1448690/3716727.aspx)

Here is my new markup:

```
 var $link='<a href="javascript: var wind= window.open(\'../EForm/Info?formId='+data.record.Form.Id+'\',\'EForm_Details\',\'height=550,width=345\');">info</a>';
```

Here is how it renders:

```
<a href="javascript: var wind= window.open('../EForm/Info?formId=1','EForm_Details','height=550,width=345');">info</a>
```

And it works perfect in all 3 browsers.